# Bases and dimensions of subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

1.Compute the basis and find the dimension of the subspace $Skew_3(\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in M_{3 \times 3}: -A = A^T \} $

The basis for the set of skew (anti-symmetric) matrices in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is

$$\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \end{array} \right)\}$$

and so $dim(skew_3(\mathbb{R})) = 3$

2. Find a basis for the subspace of polynomials $H \subset P_2( \mathbb{R} )$ where $\int_{-1}^1p(x)dx = 0$ for $p \in H$. Give its dimension.

The basis for the set in question is

$$\{ x\}$$

the basis has dimension 1.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :**

- for 1), what can you say about the $a_{ii}$ elements ?
- for 2) that's not $\{x\}$, you can detail that 
  $$\int_{-1}^1p(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1ax^2+bx+c\,dx=a\int_{-1}^1x^2dx+b\int_{-1}^1x\,dx+c\int_{-1}^11\,dx$$ and calculate the three integrals (you will find a base which is not a sub-base of $\{1,x,x^2\}$).

Comment: I just spotted that, A skew symmetric matrix has 0 diagonals.

Comment: Yes exactly : the $3$ remaining matrices are a base. I added a way to find the answer of 2).

Comment: I get $\frac{2}{3}a + 2c  \implies a = -3c$

Comment: but I don't see how this ties in with finding a basis? :(

Comment: Exactly. As it have to equals $0,$ you can say that $c=-\frac{1}{3}a$ and get for base $\{x,x^2-\frac{1}{3}\}$ : the dimension of your space is $2.$

Comment: Or $a=-3c$ which is indeed more elegant !